# How to hide or remove title bar on MAUI Blazor Hybrid

Tags: blazor, maui, titlebar

I wanna remove title bar.
I tried

> #if WINDOWS
> events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
> {
> wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
> {
> window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false;
> });
> });
> #endif

but this doesn't work. How to remove system title bar on the top of application?
I mean about this bar.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per Radzuixo's solution, this can be achieved by setting `SetBorderAndTitleBar(Boolean, Boolean)` to `false` and then set `ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar` to `false`. Please use the `MauiProgram.cs` like below:

```
using MauiApp13blazor.Data; 
using Microsoft.Maui.LifecycleEvents;
#if WINDOWS
using Microsoft.UI;
using Microsoft.UI.Windowing;
using Windows.Graphics;
#endif

namespace MauiApp13blazor;

public static class MauiProgram
{
      public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
      {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                  .UseMauiApp<App>()
                  .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                  {
                        fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                  })

  .ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>

        {


#if WINDOWS

            events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>

            {               

                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>

                {

                    IntPtr nativeWindowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);

                    WindowId nativeWindowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(nativeWindowHandle);

                    AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(nativeWindowId);

                    var p = appWindow.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;
                  
                    window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false;

                    p.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);

                });

            });

#endif

        });


        builder.Services.AddMauiBlazorWebView();
#if DEBUG
            builder.Services.AddBlazorWebViewDeveloperTools();
#endif
            
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();

            return builder.Build();
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved my problem by edit MauiProgram.cs

```
        builder.ConfigureLifecycleEvents(events =>
        {

#if WINDOWS
            events.AddWindows(wndLifeCycleBuilder =>
            {                
                wndLifeCycleBuilder.OnWindowCreated(window =>
                {
                    IntPtr nativeWindowHandle = WinRT.Interop.WindowNative.GetWindowHandle(window);
                    WindowId nativeWindowId = Win32Interop.GetWindowIdFromWindow(nativeWindowHandle);
                    AppWindow appWindow = AppWindow.GetFromWindowId(nativeWindowId);
                    var p = appWindow.Presenter as OverlappedPresenter;

                    window.ExtendsContentIntoTitleBar = false;
                    window.CenterOnScreen(400, 750);
                    p.SetBorderAndTitleBar(false, false);
                });
            });
#endif
        });
```

Comment: Good job, could you please send the whole content of `MauiProgram.cs`?